# Syntax Highlighter: can't find brush for XML

Tags: syntax-highlighting, syntaxhighlighter

I've been using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) for some time without any problems.

However, I recently restyled my blog and now when one page loads - a page which uses the XML brush - I get a popup saying

> Can't find brush for: xml

I've checked and double-checked, and I'm absolutely certain that the shBrushXML.js file *is* being included in the downloaded JavaScript bundle (I can see `SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Xml` in the minified JS).

I've also tested using other syntaxes on the same page and they're ok; it's just the XML brush.

Does anyone have any ideas why the XML brush is causing this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was caused by a small bug in another brush script (*i.e.* another SyntaxHighlighter brush).

I was also referencing a third party Razor syntax brush from [here](http://olioliolioioioi.blogspot.pt/2013/04/razor-brush-for-alex-gorbatchevs.html). This script has the line

```
SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Xml = Brush;
```

Which should obviously be

```
SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Razor = Brush;
```

Presumably this has been caused by the author copying the contents of the XML brush and then modifying it for Razor. On its own the XML brush worked, and on its own the Razor brush worked. The XML brush also worked when it was referenced *after* the Razor brush, and the Razor brush worked when it was referenced *after* the XML brush.

And now it's clear why.

Comment: Thank you for posting this!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Then I found that I was using `lang=XML`. However file `shBrushXml.js` had brush alias as `xml`. I made 2 changes which fixed the issue for me.

1. updated `lang=xml` in my file where I wanted syntax highlighting.
2. Updated `shBrushXml.js`
   Changed 
   `SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Xml = Brush;`
   To
   `SyntaxHighlighter.brushes.Razor = Brush;`